# black borders to the left of objects in opencv SGBM depth map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Calibrated 2 same cameras with Opencv StereoCalib.
I've got 0.32109 RMS error
and 0.386568 average reprogection error
[results of calibrating](http://oi58.tinypic.com/30tgylc.jpg)

I think this is not big calibration error.
But am getting [this depth map](http://oi59.tinypic.com/x1hwuw.jpg) with opencv SGBM algorithm with black left borders

```
 int sgbmWinSize = 9;
    int cn = img1.channels();
    sgbm->setPreFilterCap(63);
    sgbm->setBlockSize(sgbmWinSize);
    sgbm->setP1(8 * cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize);
    sgbm->setP2(32 * cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize);
    sgbm->setMinDisparity(0);
    sgbm->setNumDisparities(numberOfDisparities);
    sgbm->setUniquenessRatio(10);
    sgbm->setSpeckleWindowSize(100);
    sgbm->setSpeckleRange(32);
    sgbm->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
    sgbm->setMode(alg > 1 ? StereoSGBM::MODE_HH : StereoSGBM::MODE_SGBM);
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Non-occluded area mask
>   In  addition  to  disparity  maps,  for  stereo  match-
>   ing  method evaluation it is  interesting to  have a non-
>   occluded  area  mask.    This  mask  represents  in  white
>   color the pixels on the scene that are visible from both
>   cameras and  in  black color  the pixels that  are visible
>   from only one camera

problem "solved" with

```
for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
   for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
       if(imageData[y*width+x]==0){
          imageData[y*width+x]=x>width/2?imageData[y*width+x+1]:imageData[y*width+x-1];}}}
```